# Websocket handshake error with Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I am using `Socket.io` in a webpage, but it doesn't work. In the `console.log` I get the following error:

```
socket.io.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.somewebpage.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=uoSGxATXKabezBn8AABP' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I have this Nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://melo;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

What can I check to solve this?

Comment: Can you paste the full error message. I think you may be missing something in that location block that you may find in the error itself.